# Rails: Update user field on each request (how to optimize)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, optimization, logging

I have to update a field in the MySQL database on each HTTP request (number of page visits). Sometimes I have to do this for static files also. In the heavy-load environment this can potentially block responses because the MySQL database can perform a single update (per record) process at a time.

I was thinking of

- appending to a file and parse it in the background every X minutes
- writing log records to the MySQL database (special table) and do a
  background processing

How would you optimize that?

Comment: You have one counter that covers all page views?

Comment: @FrederickCheung No no... I just put that as an example. Actually I log bandwidth for some files (per logged user).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not convinced by what you've said about MySQL - more than one update can happen concurrently.

If you do reach mysql's concurrency limits, have you considered using a different data store for this information? For example mongodb is very well adapted to these sorts of upsert operations, as it has a wide range of "fire and forget" update operations known as [modifiers](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-ModifierOperations)

For example you can do something like

```
db.pagecounters.update({name: 'x'}, {$inc: {count: 1}}, true)
```

This would find the pagecounter object with name x and either increment count by 1 (if count exists) or set count to 1. If there was no such page counter, it would create one

Comment: This is great! By default, the Mongo Ruby driver is 'fire and forget'.